# EXTJS 5 Chart ToolTip Using "sencha-charts" on require[] not working

Tags: mvvm, sencha-charts, extjs5, appjs

Im currently using ExtJs5 MVVM architecture and I require "sencha-chart" than "ext-chart" on the app.json file, Charts works fine but adding tooltip on the bar series im using doesn't work. No error logs.

I also check their example on sencha chart kitchensink (which chart tooltip is working) found out that they require "ext-chart" for that. My code for bar series with tooltip config:

```
series: [{
     type: 'bar',
     xField: 'name',
     yField: ['data1'],
         style: {
                opacity: 0.80
        },
        highlight: {
                fill: '#000',
                'stroke-width': 20,
                stroke: '#fff'
        },
        tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                style: 'background: #FFF',
                height: 20,
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + '%');
                }


                }

    }]
```

Is there something wrong with my codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs one small change "tips" for EXTjs 5 becomes "tooltip."

```
tooltip: {
    trackMouse: true,
    style: 'background: #FFF',
    height: 20,
    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
         this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + '%');
    }
}
```

However, there are a lot of bugs with the EXTjs 5 charts.  I had this same issue, and submitted a bug to Sencha:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289313-Sencha-EXTjs-5-Charts-Broken-Tooltips

Comment: Yes, I got it already. Thanks Josh.

Also I think I need to add this configuration "interactions": 'itemhighlight' for example for it to work.

Comment: Hi Josh, try to add interactions configuration. tried including it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
tooltip: {
trackMouse: true,
style: 'background: #FFF',
height: 20,
renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
     this.setHtml(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + '%');
}    
}
```

I used `tooltip` inplace of `tips` and `this.setHtml()` in place of `this.setTitle()` ,and it worked for me.